# Most efficient way to rename a content stream with CMIS

Tags: filenames, cmis

Every CMIS document has:

- a **contentStream** (for instance a video, as a binary)
- a **contentStreamFileName** (for instance `myvideo.ogv`)

*(well except CMIS documents that have a null content stream)*

Paragraph 2.1.4.3.3 of the [CMIS 1.1 specification](http://docs.oasis-open.org/cmis/CMIS/v1.1/cs01/CMIS-v1.1-cs01.html#x1-29300018) says that **contentStreamFileName** is NOT updatable.

So, when a CMIS client wants to rename `myvideo.ogv` to `cinematon.ogv`, how should it do?

Anything more efficient than downloading and [re-uploading the same binary with a different name](http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/chemistry-dev/201312.mbox/%3Cd6c66d069c1591b23d73f3ed5e7b300b-EhVcXl9JQQFXRwQFDQkEXR0wfgZLV15fQUBFBEFYXS9aBFgIVQkjAVVfDwkJFE8AXVpYSlJWWAgwXnUJU1xZV1dITQ==-webmailer2@server01.webmailer.hosteurope.de%3E)?
The binary can be several gigabytes.

Comment: Can you Move the content to the same place, but with a new name?

Comment: @Gagravarr: I just checked `2.2.4.15 moveObject Moves the speciﬁed ﬁle-able object from one folder to another`. It does not take a contentStreamFileName or anything similar as argument. It only takes `repositoryId`, `objectId`, `targetFolderId`, `sourceFolderId` :-(

Comment: Ah, worth a shot... Hopefully our resident expert @florian-müller will be along shortly to explain the tick!

Answer (score 1):

A generic CMIS client cannot rename a content stream without replacing the content (with the same content).
There is no unified definition among repositories how the content stream filename is handled. That's why the property is read-only.

Some repositories allow changing the filename, but how is repository specific.